# Can I use HTTPS connection without using a (libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll) files?

Tags: delphi, dll, indy, delphi-xe7

I do expect the answer is no but maybe I'm wrong !

Is there any way to use HTTPS connection without use DLL files (libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll)  ???

Or can I embedded them in my application and establish the HTTPS connection without extract them ?

I use indy library in my application `Idhttp`...

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762000/use-ssl-with-delphi-yet-still-having-a-single-exe

Comment: Why on earth wouldn't you want to use these files? This separation is what lets you respond to security vulnerabilities quickly. Your users will appreciate you caring for their security.

Comment: Use the WinHTTP API - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725348/winhttp-delphi-wrapper

Comment: Or MSXML2_TLB's XMLHTTP component http://yoy.be/msxml2.html

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to use HTTPS connection without use DLL files (libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll) ???

You can use any SSL library you want, all you need is a wrapper component that is derived from `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase`. And then you can assign that component to the `TIdHTTP.IOHandler` property before accessing an HTTPS url.

Indy provides such a component for OpenSSL (`TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`), but Indy is not dependent on OpenSSL specifically.  You can write your own component, or use a 3rd party one (like the one provided in Eldos SecureBlackBox).

Even if you use OpenSSL, Indy 10 does have an `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders_static.pas` unit for static linking OpenSSL. It is primarily meant for iOS only, but it could be adapted to work on other platforms, if you have suitable OBJs for it.

> Or can I embedded them in my application and establish the HTTPS connection without extract them ?

If you use the OpenSSL DLLs, you need to use them as DLLs, which means extracting them first.

Comment: OK, I tried to use `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase` and assign it to `TIdHTTP.IOHandler ` but this exception **Abstract Error** is show to me !

Comment: @jumior So what? Trying stuff at random usually ends this way. Did you ever have much success coding with a complex system without understanding? Programming is hard. Don't trivialise it. Don't imagine that you can write correct code with no understanding.

Comment: @junior.programmer you cannot use `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase` **directly** in `TIdHTTP.IOHandler`. It is an abstract base class. Read my answer again more carefully, I said you have to use a component that is **derived from** `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase`. `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` is one such component.